# What is the StatementParameterizationType plan attribute?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, execution-plan

I have noticed execution plans sometimes include a `StatementParameterizationType` attribute.

[image: Properties window]

What is this, what does it mean, and when does it appear?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `StatementParameterizationType` attribute indicates the type of [parameterization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide#PlanReuse) applied to the statement.

The values are documented in [`sys.query_store_query`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-query-transact-sql):

- 0 = None
- 1 = User
- 2 = Simple
- 3 = Forced

It appears on the root node of **post-execution** ("actual") plans only.

The [**Query Store**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store) must also be **enabled** to see this attribute (e.g. in SSMS).

---

[AdventureWorks](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/adventureworks) demo:

```
USE AdventureWorks2017;
GO
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION CLEAR PROCEDURE_CACHE;
ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE;
GO
-- None (0)
SELECT COUNT_BIG(*)
FROM Production.Product AS P 
WHERE P.Color = N'Red';
GO
-- User (1)
EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql
    @stmt = N'
        SELECT COUNT_BIG(*)
        FROM Production.Product AS P 
        WHERE P.Color = @Color;',
    @params = N'@Color nvarchar(15)',
    @Color = N'Red';
GO
-- Simple (2)
SELECT A.AddressID
FROM Person.[Address] AS A
WHERE A.AddressLine1 = N'1 Smiling Tree Court';
GO
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION CLEAR PROCEDURE_CACHE;
ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET PARAMETERIZATION FORCED;
GO
-- Forced (3)
SELECT COUNT_BIG(*)
FROM Production.Product AS P 
WHERE P.Color = N'Red';
```